# Hibernate criteria when using mapped classes

Tags: java, hibernate

I have created an object which maps two tables in my database, the Dictionary table and the Token table.   The object (class) that represents the join between these two tables is called DictionaryToken.

Here is the class:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.FetchType;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
 import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


@Entity
@Table(name="dictionary", catalog="emscribedxcode")
```

public class DictionaryToken {
    private static Logger  LOG = Logger.getLogger(DictionaryToken.class);

```
private Long _seq;
private String _code;
private String _acute;
private String _gender;
private String _codeType;
private String _papplydate;
private String _capplydate;
private Long _tokenLength;
private List <TokenDictionary> _token;
private int _type;
private String _system;
private String _physicalsystem;
/*
 * type of 0 is a straight line insert type of 1 is a language dictionary
 * entyr type of 2 is a multiple token entry
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "seq")
public Long getSeq() {
    return _seq;
}
public void setSeq(Long seq_) {
    _seq = seq_;
}

@Column(name = "code")
public String getCode() {
    return _code;
}
public void setCode(String code_) {
    _code = code_;
}

@Column(name = "acute")
public String getAcute() {
    return _acute;
}
public void setAcute(String acute_) {
    _acute = acute_;
}

@Column(name = "gender")
public String getGender() {
    return _gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender_) {
    _gender = gender_;
}

@Column(name = "codetype")
public String getCodeType() {
    return _codeType;
}
public void setCodeType(String codeType_) {
    _codeType = codeType_;
}

@Column(name = "papplydate")
public String getPapplydate() {
    return _papplydate;
}
public void setPapplydate(String papplydate_) {
    _papplydate = papplydate_;
}

@Column(name = "capplydate")
public String getCapplydate() {
    return _capplydate;
}
public void setCapplydate(String capplydate_) {
    _capplydate = capplydate_;
}


@Column(name = "token_length")
public Long getTokenLength() {
    return _tokenLength;
}
public void setTokenLength(Long tokenLength_) {
    _tokenLength = tokenLength_;
}
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "dictionarytoken", targetEntity = TokenDictionary.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<TokenDictionary> get_token() {
    return _token;
}
public void set_token(List<TokenDictionary> _token) {
    this._token = _token;
}
public void addToToken(TokenDictionary token){
    this._token.add(token);
}
@Column(name = "type")
public int getType() {
    return _type;
}
public void setType(int _type) {
    this._type = _type;
}
@Column(name = "physicalsystem")
public String get_physicalsystem() {
    return _physicalsystem;
}
public void set_physicalsystem(String _physicalsystem) {
    this._physicalsystem = _physicalsystem;
}
@Column(name = "codingsystem")
public String get_system() {
    return _system;
}
public void set_system(String _system) {
    this._system = _system;
}



   }
```

Here is my problem.    I can perform queries using a service with this object with no problems UNLESS I add a criteria.  Here is the method which retrieves the entries

```
public List<DictionaryToken> getDictionaryTokenEntries(String system) {
    Session session = null;
    List<DictionaryToken> dictonaries = new ArrayList<DictionaryToken>();
    try {
        session = HibernateUtils.beginTransaction("emscribedxcode");
           session.createCriteria(Dictionary.class).addOrder(Order.desc("codeType"))

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DictionaryToken.class);
                  /*******THIS IS THE PROBLEM STATEMENT*************************/
        if (system != null) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("codingsystem", system));
        }
                  /****************************************************************/
        // dictonaries = criteria.list();
        Order order = Order.asc("seq");
        criteria.addOrder(order);
        dictonaries = criteria.list();
        System.out.println("Dictionaryentries = " + dictonaries.size());

        // System.out.println("Dictionaries entries EVICT start...");
        // for(Dictionary dic : dictonaries){
        // session.evict(dic);
        // }
        // System.out.println("Dictionaries entries EVICT end");
    } catch (HibernateException e_) {
        e_.printStackTrace();
        NTEVENT_LOG.error("Error while getting List of Dictionary entries");
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            try {
                HibernateUtils.closeSessions();
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return dictonaries;
}
```

When I add the criteria, I get the following error:

org.hibernate.QueryException:  could not resolve property: coding system of : com.artificialmed.domain.dictionary.model.DictionaryToken

I know that it has something to do with the nature of the object which is really a join between my dictionary class and the underlying table and my token class and table.

The field codingsystem is a field in my dictionary class.    I think I am suppose to use aliases but I don't know how to do this under the current circumstances.    Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Elliott

Comment: Try `Restrictions.eq("system", system)`, you have get_system (why not getSystem?) getter, so property name should be "system", "codingsystem" is a name of the column in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a newbie problem.   Hibernate requires the getters and setters of the models that reflect the tables to be of a specific format.  The getter MUST BE get+ where name is the fieldname in the underlying table.    The setter MUST BE set+ where name is the fieldname of the underlying table.   And yes the first letter of Name must capitalized.